# java Arrays.binarySearch fails to find target

Tags: java, binary-search

```
String[] sortedArray = new String[]{"Quality", "Name", "Testing", "Package"};   

// Search for the word "cat" 
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(sortedArray, "Quality");
```

I always get `-3`. Problem is in `"Name"`. Why I can not have `"Name"` in my array? Any idea?

Comment: "Name" should be before "Quality", and "Package" should be before "Testing".

Comment: binarySearch is only for sorted array.

Comment: @Jon, I think you meant that "Package" should come before "Quality".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In order to use `binarySearch`, you will need to sort the array yourself first:

```
String[] sortedArray = new String[]{"Quality", "Name", "Testing", "Package"};   

java.util.Arrays.sort(sortedArray);

int index = Arrays.binarySearch(sortedArray, "Quality");
```

Answer (score 6):

The array is must be sorted. From Javadoc of binarySearch():

> The range must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural ordering of its elements prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.

Answer (score 2):

An array must be sorted for binary search to work.  The javadoc for [binarySearch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) says this:

> The array must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural ordering  of its elements (as by the sort(Object[]) method) prior to making this call. **If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.**

(Emphasis added.)

And the reason is simple.  The binary search *algorithm* has a precondition that the input array is sorted.